# JS window.location issue

Tags: javascript

I use this code for a redirection form when selecting a different jersey from the select input but while the JSfiddle works at my site there is no redirection from the window.location command.

https://jsfiddle.net/giorgoskey/95k1tc0b/4/

```js
function populateSecondTextBox() {
  var p = document.getElementById('your_name');
  var txt = document.getElementById('txtFirst');
  p.textContent = txt.value;
}

function populateNumberTextBox() {
  var p = document.getElementById('your_number');
  var txt = document.getElementById('txtSecond');
  p.textContent = txt.value;
}

var goBtn = document.getElementById("goBtn");
var shirts = document.getElementById("shirts");

goBtn.onclick = function() {
  window.location = shirts.value;
}
```

Comment: Did you attempt to debug your code using your browser development tools?

Comment: Change the form name to id and di `document.getElementById("cityselect").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.action = this.shirts.value;
})`

Comment: The code you presented is not the code in your jsfiddle.  In that code, your form submits to a function redirectTo, that doesn't exist.  you don't [have a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.  Update your question so it's complete and reproducible.

Comment: The main issue with this question [has already been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hou have to use history.pusthState()

[MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

```js
history.pushState(state, title [, url])
```

empty state and title.

```js
window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
```

in your case

```js
var goBtn = document.getElementById("goBtn");
var shirts = document.getElementById("shirts");

goBtn.onclick = function() {
    window.history.pushState({}, '', shirts.value);
}
```

Comment: Yes Robert that was the issue, thanks for the help!!